# Passing params across components in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In my ReactNative application, I'm trying to pass some data across components using "route" in Navigation stack. I'm sending as in below code:

```
navigation.navigate('OtpScreen', { otpKey: '1234' });
```

I'm capturing in OtpScreen as below:

```
const OTPScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
   const { otpKey }= route.params;
}
```

Its throwing undefined 'params' when this screen is presented.
I've gone through sample code available in [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Glossary%20of%20terms%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.1.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.3.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.1.6%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.1.6%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.2.6%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E0.7.3%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.4.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fnavigate.js)

What could be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in the recent version of ReactNative, I've to use below line of code to fetch the params from navigation.

```
const otpKey = navigation.getParam('otpKey', '');
```

I think, we can't use "parmas" any more.

Answer (score 0):

Below your render type this

```
const param = route.params.otpKey;
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But please observe that, I'm using navigation & route as part of the parameters and so it has to be "route.params.otpKey". I'll edit your answer. But its still not working.